# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float' when added extra operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, encoding

I am new to Data-preprocessing in Python for Machine Learning. I am trying to preprocess some data. The data consists of many categorical variables with some empty and NaN entries. I am doing filling the empty or NaN spaces using ffil method, then doing label-encode using sklearn LabelEncoder and later one-hot encoding. I have two different codes segments. The first one is little simpler where doing label encoding gives no error but in the second case which has few addintional processes I am getting the above-mentioned error:
The first code section:

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
for cols in train.keys():
    if(cols.startswith('cat')):
        train[cols].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
        train[cols].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
        if train[cols].dtype == 'object':
            train[cols] = encoder.fit_transform(train[cols])
            train = pd.get_dummies(data=train, columns=[cols])
```

Second code section:

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
best_fit = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
for cols in train.keys():
    if(cols.startswith('cat')):
        train[cols].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
        train[cols].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
        if train[cols].dtype == 'object':
            train[cols] = encoder.fit_transform(train[cols])
            train_temp = pd.get_dummies(data=train, columns=[cols])
            temp_df = train_temp[list(set(train_temp.keys())-set(train.keys()))]
            fit_temp = best_fit.fit(temp_df, target)
            features_temp = fit_temp.transform(temp_df)
            train = train.drop([cols], axis=1)
            train = pd.concat([train, pd.DataFrame(features_temp)], axis = 1, join='outer')
```

The Traceback log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-4efe4593ba69>", line 37, in <module>
    train[cols] = encoder.fit_transform(train[cols])

  File "C:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 112, in fit_transform
    self.classes_, y = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)

  File "C:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 211, in unique
    perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Issue Resolved:
Looks like some internal error. Restarting the machine and executing the script again solved the problem.

Comment: If you are asking about the error message you put in the question title, then please include the full traceback in the question, and also indicate which of the source lines you have posted it refers to.

Comment: @Duncan added the log. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs due to the fact that the data must be of uniform datatype while passing it to the encoder i.e convert the column to one dtype when passing it to the encoder.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,'NAN','4']})

encoder.fit_transform(df['a'].astype(str))
#or if you have only numerical datatype then
#encoder.fit_transform(pd.to_numeric(df['a'],errors='coerce'))
```

Comment: Didn't the solution work? Did you try? It might be because of this line `train[cols].fillna(value="", inplace=True)`, you are adding a string into the dataframe and there might be numbers too

Comment: it seems to be some memory issue or else. After restarting the machine and executing the code previously throwing error worked.